# Function not found in my Controlller class

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a personal project and I'm facing an error where I'm using a function from another class in another java file and it's not being found but I have it defined in the respective class

EventView.js:

```js
displayEvent(event){
    this.EventTitle = event.eventName
    this.EventDate =  event.eventDay + "\n" + event.eventTime
}
```

EventController.js:

```js
class EventController{

    constructor(model, view){
        this.model= model
        this.view = view

        this.onEventChanged(this.model.event_)
        this.view.bindChanges(this.handleEditEventName,this.handleEditEventDay,this.handleEditEventTime)
        this.model.bindChanges(this.onEventChanged)
    }

    onEventChanged = event => {
        this.view.displayEvent(event)
    }
```

The error message

```
> EventController.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: this.view.displayEvent is not a function
    at EventController.onEventChanged (EventController.js:13)
    at new EventController (EventController.js:7)
    at EventController.js:31
```

P.S I need an efficient way of using classes from other files, right now I just load all the scripts in the HTML document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should not be using arrow functions in your `EventController` class, because by doing that the `this` in the function will not refer to the class itself. It should probably be declared as a regular function as such:

```
class EventController{

    constructor(model, view){
        this.model= model
        this.view = view

        this.onEventChanged(this.model.event_)
        this.view.bindChanges(this.handleEditEventName,this.handleEditEventDay,this.handleEditEventTime)
        this.model.bindChanges(this.onEventChanged)
    }

    onEventChanged(event) {
        this.view.displayEvent(event)
    }
}
```

In fact, [arrow functions are "ill suited as methods"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) because they bind to the lexical `this`.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my problem, I hadn't created a eventModel object and eventView object on the data I was testing so that's why it didn't recognize the function